# Snow Leopard QTJava Support

Tags: java, macos, quicktime

**I am looking for information regarding support for QTJava on the latest Mac OS, 10.6.**

An application we are developing that worked fine both on 10.4 and 10.5 is now getting unexpected crashes on load when ran on 10.6.

In the past we have had to strip out the 64bit architecture from the Java application stub because the QuickTime libraries QTJAva was referencing would not run in 64bit mode (Java 6). But even with this removed the crashing is still occurring on 10.6, leaving me to believe this is more of a QuickTime specific issue.

**Has QTJava been depreciated with the release of Quicktime X, or is this likely to be more of a Java 64bit issue?**

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be deprecated according to [this post from last year](http://lists.apple.com/archives/quicktime-java/2008/Jun/msg00018.html):

> I am currently attending 2008 Apple WWDC conference. 
>   Apple announced today they will release new OS (10.6
>   Snow Leopard) in year 2009.  Instead of QuickTime 7.X,
>   QuickTime X will accompany the new OS.  Apple also
>   officially announced today that QTJava will be
>   deprecated  once QuickTime X becomes available.

Additional information on the subject seems very sparse, though.

Comment: +1 It IS deprecated. Using the QTJava API within Netbeans on snow leopard produces the strike-through deprecated syntax highlighting for all parts of the QTJava API. See question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895142/alternative-options-for-displaying-video-in-java for other video alternatives