# Alternative options for displaying video in Java?

Tags: java, swing, video, cross-platform, quicktime

At the moment I use [QuickTime for Java](http://developer.apple.com/quicktime/qtjava/) to display video in a swing application. However, Apple has deprecated support for QTJava and I was wondering what options other are available right *now*+ for moving forward?

Requirements:

- Must be cross platform (WIN & OSX).
- Must be able to support many different video formats.
- Must be capable of supporting large videos (i.e. Hi-Def).
- API must provide access to raw frames and audio tracks.

+JMC could be included in Java7, whenever that turns up and at the moment you can dig it out of JavaFX... But I don't want to bundle all of JavaFX with my application right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most definitely want [Xuggle](http://www.xuggle.com/)! It's very easy to use and is a Swiss Army chainsaw of Java multimedia processing.

Comment: Now the site raises warnings in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Something called JVLC supposedly exists; Java bindings for [VideoLAN Client](http://www.videolan.org/).  However, [the JVLC site](http://trac.videolan.org/jvlc/) has been broken since spring, so I'm finding it difficult to get further information.  Something like this should definitely be what you're looking for, though.

Here's a link to someone hosting its Javadoc:
http://vlc4osgi.forge.os4os.org/javadoc/org/videolan/jvlc/JVLC.html

It seems you can also embed mplayer in Java using [JMPlayer](http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2008/01/30/jmplayer/).  VLC would be my first instinct, though.

**Edit:**
Hm... The site in the last link I posted mentions [Java Media Framework](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/).

Comment: With the JVLC site down, is it possible to download it?

Answer (score 1):

What about JMF? I used it once and it worked quite fine (for MPEG layer2, I don't know which other formats it supports).

Link: [JMF](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jack, however I struggled getting JMF to work with newer, more popular codecs.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the suggestions of Gunslinger47. Also looks as though there are bindings for [gstreamer](http://code.google.com/p/gstreamer-java/).

Answer (score 0):

I got his from [Petro Semeniuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519539/petro-semeniuk)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34038162/48136).

You may be interested by the [caprica/vlcj](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj) project.

There's even a project that showcase the integration: [caprica/vlcj-player](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-player).

At this point the project seems relatively maintained, master (future vlcj 5) branch is based on the not yet released version of VLC 4. Stable version ([4.8.2](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/uk.co.caprica/vlcj/4.8.2) at this time) is available for VLC 3.x version.