# Creating video player using Java

Tags: java, video-player

I need to create a video player using Java for my project. I have already checked many examples on the Internet. Some of them run, but do not show any screen, I can only hear the sound of the video. Please help me solve this...

I am using the below import

```
import javax.media.*;
```

EDIT:
Below is the code that i use:

```
import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.io.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import javax.media.*;

 public class MediaPlayerDemo extends JFrame 
 {
     private Player player;
     private File file;

     public MediaPlayerDemo()
     {
         super( "Demonstrating the Java Media Player" );

         JButton openFile = new JButton( "Open file to play" );
         openFile.addActionListener( new ActionListener() 
         {
             public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
             {
                 openFile();
                 createPlayer();
             }
         });
         getContentPane().add( openFile, BorderLayout.NORTH );

         setSize( 300, 300 );
         show();
     }

     private void openFile()
     {
         JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

         fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode( JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY );
         int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog( this );

         // user clicked Cancel button on dialog
         if ( result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION )
             file = null;
         else
             file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
     }

     private void createPlayer()
     {
         if ( file == null )
             return;

         removePreviousPlayer();

         try 
         {
             // create a new player and add listener
             player = Manager.createPlayer( file.toURL() );
             player.addControllerListener( new EventHandler() );
             player.start(); // start player
         }
         catch ( Exception e )
         {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this, "Invalid file or location", "Error loading file",
             JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
         }
     }

     private void removePreviousPlayer()
     {
         if ( player == null )
             return;

         player.close();

         Component visual = player.getVisualComponent();
         Component control = player.getControlPanelComponent();

         Container c = getContentPane();

         if ( visual != null )
             c.remove( visual );

         if ( control != null )
             c.remove( control );
     }

     public static void main(String args[])
     {
         MediaPlayerDemo app = new MediaPlayerDemo();

         app.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() 
         {
             public void windowClosing( WindowEvent e )
             {
                 System.exit(0);
             }
         });
     }

     // inner class to handler events from media player
     private class EventHandler implements ControllerListener 
     {
         public void controllerUpdate( ControllerEvent e ) 
         {
             if ( e instanceof RealizeCompleteEvent ) 
             {
                 Container c = getContentPane();

                 // load Visual and Control components if they exist
                 Component visualComponent = player.getVisualComponent();

                 if ( visualComponent != null )
                     c.add( visualComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER );

                 Component controlsComponent = player.getControlPanelComponent();

                 if ( controlsComponent != null )
                     c.add( controlsComponent, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

                 c.doLayout();
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Please share code which you have tried.

Comment: Can you be more specific that where exactly you are getting error in code?

Comment: I can run the code but I don't know why I only can hear the sound of the video that i select but it doesn't show the screen.

Comment: you can try the java media framework api which makes it easier to create multimedia applications. Refer this link for more detail http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077644/java-se/java-media-framework-player-api.html

Answer (score 8):

I used [vlcj](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj) and it worked smoothly. It's java binding to vlcj player and the good thing that you don't have to provide any drives since vlcj already includes all of them in binary distribution.

Give it a go, there is [example of already working player](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-player) built for you!

Comment: supposed that i want to distribute my player, how can i do this if the users have the vlc library installed in a place tha isn't the default place?

Comment: That one is no use on Mac, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Hasen actually it was working for me on MacOS almost out of the box.

Comment: @Petro Semeniuk It only works with Java 1.6 on Mac, that's a serious shortcoming. The author complains about Java on the mac quite a lot in the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Try a JavaFX Mediaplayer:

Usable Codecs:

- Audio: MP3; AIFF containing uncompressed PCM; WAV containing uncompressed PCM; MPEG-4 multimedia container with Advanced Audio Coding (AAC) audio
- Video: FLV containing VP6 video and MP3 audio; MPEG-4 multimedia
  container with H.264/AVC (Advanced Video Coding) video compression .

Here an example from Oracle:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.MapChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.scene.media.Track;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * A sample media player which loops indefinitely over the same video
 */
public class MediaPlayer extends Application {
private static final String MEDIA_URL = "http://someserver/somedir/somefile.mp4";

private static String arg1;

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Media Player");

// Create media player
        Media media = new Media((arg1 != null) ? arg1 : MEDIA_URL);
        javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
        mediaPlayer.setCycleCount(javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);

// Print track and metadata information
        media.getTracks().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Track>() {
public void onChanged(Change<? extends Track> change) {
                System.out.println("Track> "+change.getList());
            }
        });
        media.getMetadata().addListener(new MapChangeListener<String,Object>() {
public void onChanged(MapChangeListener.Change<? extends String, ? extends Object> change) {
                System.out.println("Metadata> "+change.getKey()+" -> "+change.getValueAdded());
            }
        });

// Add media display node to the scene graph
        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,800,600);
        root.getChildren().add(mediaView);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
if (args.length > 0) {
            arg1 = args[0];
        }
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

https://blogs.oracle.com/javafx/entry/mpeg_4_multimedia_support_in

Comment: Mediaplayer is pretty useless though since if you change the speed the pitch goes up or down with it which is not normally desirable....there's no way around it either. It's a real shortcoming.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code.

```
package New;

import java.net.URL;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.Status;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FxMediaExample2 extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // Locate the media content in the CLASSPATH
        URL mediaUrl = getClass().getResource("Test.mp4");
        String mediaStringUrl = mediaUrl.toExternalForm();

        // Create a Media
        Media media = new Media(mediaStringUrl);

        // Create a Media Player
        final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
        // Automatically begin the playback
        player.setAutoPlay(true);

        // Create a 400X300 MediaView
        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(player);

        mediaView.setFitWidth(400);
        mediaView.setFitHeight(300);
        mediaView.setSmooth(true);
        mediaView.setLayoutX(200);
        mediaView.setLayoutY(200);
        // Create the DropShadow effect
        DropShadow dropshadow = new DropShadow();
        dropshadow.setOffsetY(5.0);
        dropshadow.setOffsetX(5.0);
        dropshadow.setColor(Color.RED);

        mediaView.setEffect(dropshadow);

        Rectangle rect4 = new Rectangle(35, 55, 95, 25);
        rect4.setFill(Color.RED);
        rect4.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        rect4.setStrokeWidth(1);

        // Create the HBox
        // HBox controlBox = new HBox(5, null, null);

        // Create the VBox
        VBox root = new VBox(1, mediaView);

        GridPane gridpane = new GridPane();
        gridpane.setPadding(new Insets(95));
        gridpane.setHgap(1);
        gridpane.setVgap(10);

        GridPane.setHalignment(rect4, HPos.CENTER);

        Group grp = new Group();
        gridpane.add(root, 1, 1);

        grp.getChildren().add(gridpane);

        // Create the Scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(grp);

        // Add the scene to the Stage
        stage.setScene(scene);
        // Set the title of the Stage
        stage.setTitle("A simple Media Example");
        // Display the Stage
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java Media Framework can be used to create multimedia applications like video and audio players.